# Having trouble trying to display menu item (include 'filename.php';) based on the value of a column in a db table

Tags: php, sql, include

I am new to PHP so please forgive me, you guys have been amazing so far in my journey!

I have built a working registration and login system, and now I am trying to display or include content based on if the user is a certain level.  In their user table, they have 4 columns with levels, they default to "no" on everything other than level1.  Below is what I tried to write to display(include) something based on someone having level4 = "yes" but it just doesn't work.

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid =" .$_SESSION['userid'];
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if ($row["level4"] == 'yes'){

            include 'asidemenus/admin.php';
        }

    }
}
?>
```

I found an error I did not see.  I don't understand this, as it IS getting the userid correctly, but I do not understand the error :(

```
Fatal error
: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'justinw' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\ericksonlv.comV2\partials\aside.php:334 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\ericksonlv.comV2\partials\aside.php(334): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM u...') #1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\ericksonlv.comV2\index.php(47): include('C:\\xampp2\\htdoc...') #2 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp2\htdocs\ericksonlv.comV2\partials\aside.php
on line
334
```

Comment: echo $sql;
exit;

then check the sql is valid by running from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was just missing a couple quotes, and it was using my variable as a column name.  Here is the corrected and working code if anyone out there is trying to do the same thing.

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if ($row["level4"] == 'yes'){

            include 'asidemenus/admin.php';
        }

    }
}
?>
```